# Compose string of IPs using bash command line

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a command that returns the following:

```
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="136" id4="5" id5="0" />
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="128" id4="2" id5="0" />
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="128" id4="4" id5="0" />
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="128" id4="6" id5="0" />
```

The first four IDs combined represent an IP address (e.g. `172.17.136.5` for the first line).

I would like to pipe the above to a parsing command which will output a single string with all the IP addresses separated by spaces.

For the above example:

```
myVariable="172.17.136.5 172.17.128.2 172.17.128.4 172.17.128.6"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with an `awk` command most easily:

```
your-command | awk -F\" -v OFS=. -v ORS=' ' '{print $2, $4, $6, $8}'
```

To set it as a variable, use command substitution:

```
myVariable="$(your-command | awk -F\" -v OFS=. -v ORS=' ' '{print $2, $4, $6, $8}')"
```

---

`-F` sets the input field separator (which is by default any whitespace) to a custom value; in this case a double quote (`"`).

`-v` allows you to set `awk` variables.

`OFS` is the output field separator, by default a single space.  We set it to a period.

`ORS` is the output *record* separator, by default a newline.  We set it to a space.

Then we print the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th fields for each line of the input.

---

Sample output:

```
$ cat temp
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="136" id4="5" id5="0" />
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="128" id4="2" id5="0" />
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="128" id4="4" id5="0" />
 id1="172" id2="17" id3="128" id4="6" id5="0" />
$ myVariable="$(cat temp | awk -F\" -v OFS=. -v ORS=' ' '{print $2, $4, $6, $8}')"
$ echo "$myVariable" 
172.17.136.5 172.17.128.2 172.17.128.4 172.17.128.6 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myvariable=$(yourmysterycommand |
               sed -e 's/id1=//;
                       s/id5=.*//;
                       s/"//g;
                       s/id.=/./g;
                       s/[[:blank:]]\+//g' |
               paste -sd' ')
```

That's a one-liner, but reformatted with extra newlines and indentation for readability.

```
$ echo "$myvariable"
172.17.136.5 172.17.128.2 172.17.128.4 172.17.128.6
```

The `sed` command removes the string `id1=`, then removes `id5=` and everything following, then removes all double-quote characters (`"`), changes all occurences of `id.=` to a literal `.`, and finally removes all blank characters (spaces and/or tabs) from the line.

The `paste` command joins the lines with a space character as delimiter.

---

BTW, a better solution would be to fix whatever program is printing IP addresses in such a useless and dumb format.  An octet in an IP address is not any kind of an "id".