# Fast way to delete files with less than x lines

Tags: bash

What's a fast and not too complicated way to delete all files in a directory that are under x lines long, in bash?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a POSIX solution that should be pretty straightforward to understand:

```
find . -type f -exec awk -v x=10 'NR==x{exit 1}' {} \; -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

As in [Stephane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327375/135943), remove the `echo` when happy with what will be removed.

---

### Explanations, written for those totally new to Unix/Linux:

The dot `.` represents the current directory.  `find` finds files and directories recursively within `.`, and can do things with them.

`-type` is one of `find`'s *primaries*; it is a test that will be performed for each file and directory that is recursively found (within `.`), and the rest of the primaries on the line are only evaluated if this results in "true."

In this particular case, we only continue if we are dealing with a *regular file*, not a directory or something else (e.g. a block device.)

---

The `-exec` primary (of `find`) calls an external command, and only proceeds to the next primary if the external command exits successfully (exit status of "0").  The `{}` is replaced with the file name being "considered" by the `find` command.  So the first `-exec` call is equivalent to the following shell command, executed for each file in turn:

```
awk -v x=10 'NR==x{exit 1}' ./somefilename
```

---

**Awk is an entire language in itself,** designed for handling delimited text files such as CSVs.  The Awk conditionals and commands (which are contained between single quotes and start with the letters `NR`) are executed for every line of a text file.  (Implicit looping.)

To learn Awk fully, I highly recommend [the Grymoire Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html), but I will explain the Awk features used in the above command.

---

The `-v` flag to Awk allows us to set an Awk variable (once) before the Awk commands are executed (for each line of the file.)  In this case we set `x` to `10`.

---

`NR` is a special Awk variable referring to the "**N**umber of the current **R**ecord."  In other words, it is the line number we are looking at in any particular pass through the loop.

(Note that it *is* possible, though unusual, to use a different "**R**ecord **S**eparator" than the default of a newline character, by setting `RS`.  [Here is an example of playing with record separators.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291988/135943))

---

Awk scripts in general consist of *conditions* (outside curly braces) combined with *actions* (inside curly braces.)  There can be compound conditions and compound actions, and there is a default condition (true) and a default action (print), but we needn't bother with those.

The *condition* here is, "Is this the 10th line?"  If this is the case, we exit with a non-zero exit status, which in shell scripting means "unsuccessful command termination."

Thus **the only way this Awk command will exit *successfully* is if the end of the file is reached before the 10th line is reached.**

So if the Awk script exits successfully, it means you have a file of less than ten lines.

---

The next `-exec` call (if you remove the `echo`) will remove each file (that gets that far in evaluation of `find`'s primaries) by running:

```
rm -f ./somefilename
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a `find` implementation that supports the `-readable` predicate (if your `find` doesn't support it, just remove it, you'll just get error messages for non-readable files, or replace with `-exec test -r {} \;`):

```
x=10 find . -type f -readable -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    lines=$(wc -l < "$file") && [ "$((lines))" -lt "$x" ] && echo rm -f "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```

Remove the `echo` if happy.

That's not particularly efficient in that it counts *all* the lines in every file while it only needs to stop at the `x`<sup>th</sup> one and it runs one `wc` (and potentially one `rm`) command for each file.

With GNU `awk`, you can make it a lot more efficient with:

```
x=10
find . -type f -readable -exec awk -v x="$x" -v ORS='\0' '
  FNR == x {nextfile}
  ENDFILE {if (FNR < x) print FILENAME}' {} +|
  xargs -r0 echo rm -f
```

(again, remove `echo` when happy).

The same with `perl`:

```
x=10 find . -type f -readable -exec perl -Tlne '
  if ($. == $ENV{x}) {close ARGV}
  elsif (eof) {print $ARGV; close ARGV}' {} +
```

Replace `print` with `unlink` if happy.

Comment: 1. What's the last `sh` for? 2. Is `wc -l < "$file"` faster than `wc -l "$file"`? 3. How does sh know the value of `$x`, which is defined in the calling Bash shell?

Comment: @tomas, the last `sh` is what goes in that inline script's `$0`, to be used for error messages for instance. `wc -l "$file"` would print the file name which we don't want here and would run `wc` even if the file can't be opened. `$x` is exported to `find` (`x=10 find...`) which itself passes it to `sh`.

Comment: Thanks! But I guess this error that I get on OSX means that my Bash version does not support the -readable flag? `find: -readable: unknown primary or operator`.

Comment: @durrrutti, that's not down to `bash`. `bash` is just a command-line interpreter, but of the `find` implementation. `-readable` is a GNU extension, not available in OS/X `find`. It's only used to limit to the files that are readable (you wouldn't be able to get the line count for non-readable files). You can omit it for the first one, you'd then just get error messages when opening the files for `wc` for the files that are not readable.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, this answer is so tricky I'm left wondering: Did I miss any edge cases with my answer?  :)

Comment: @Wildcard, the idea is to try and run as few commands as possible if the intent is for it to be _fast_

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, aside AWK you can also use GNU sed to achieve the same result:

```
find . -type f -exec sed 11q1 '{}' ';' -exec echo rm -f '{}' ';'
```

Which results in a bit more concise command line.

**Explanation**

```
11 - is the address, i.e. "the eleventh line"
q - is for _q_uit (abort the execution)
1 - is the exit code parameter for q (GNU sed extension)
```