# Find pattern on multiple lines within BIG log files

Tags: text-processing, logs, forensics

To investigate within logs, I am trying to find the very first time a vulnerability in a workflow has been exploited.

The pattern is on multiple lines.

The pattern would be

```
AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC
```

The problem is that

```
AAAAAAAAA
```

or

```
BBBBBBBBB
```

or

```
CCCCCCCCC
```

Can be found anywhere indivdually in the log without showing the vulnerability; it is the exact pattern in this exact order that will help me.

For example

`grep -Ei "AAAAAAAAA|BBBBBBBBB|CCCCCCCCC" logfile` does not help me since all the lines with individual occurence of `AAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBB CCCCCCCCC` will be there.

How can I solve this?

Comment: There are quite a number of "multiline match" questions - this one for example [Multiline Regexp (grep, sed, awk, perl)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346994/multiline-regexp-grep-sed-awk-perl) looks close to yours

Comment: I don't think a multi-line regular expression is going to work in this context.  since it would need to be `AAAAA.*BBBBB.*CCCCC` and each candidate `AAAAA` would force grep to span the rest of the "Big" file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do it in python (I added to your example a bit to prove that you can still get the matches you desire even if there are random single lines of AAAAAAAAA, BBBBBBBBB, or CCCCCCCCC dispersed throughout the logfile) :

**below are the contents of find_log_vulns.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import re

test_string = """1234324
AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC
absdfjv4er4
AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC
123466666
AAAAAAAAA
ghrhvhhhfh
BBBBBBBBB
fjwjefjsjfjwjf
CCCCCCCCC
24wfsgggg
AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC
zzzz"""

matches = re.findall('AAAAAAAAA\nBBBBBBBBB\nCCCCCCCCC\n', test_string, re.MULTILINE)

print(matches)
```

**The result I get from running the above:**

```
$ ./find_log_vulns.py
['AAAAAAAAA\nBBBBBBBBB\nCCCCCCCCC\n', 'AAAAAAAAA\nBBBBBBBBB\nCCCCCCCCC\n', 'AAAAAAAAA\nBBBBBBBBB\nCCCCCCCCC\n']
```

As shown above, each match will be returned as an element in a list.

Answer (score 1):

using ripgrep:

```
rg -U 'A+\nB+\nC+' in
2:AAAAAAAAA
3:BBBBBBBBB
4:CCCCCCCCC
6:AAAAAAAAA
7:BBBBBBBBB
8:CCCCCCCCC
16:AAAAAAAAA
17:BBBBBBBBB
18:CCCCCCCCC
```

you can get rid of the line numbers, and so on.  If you need separators between the matches you can do this:

```
rg -U 'A+\nB+\nC+' in | rg --passthru -e '(^A)' -r $'\n'A

AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC

AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC

AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v ptrn="AAAAAAAAA\0BBBBBBBBB\0CCCCCCCCC\0" '
BEGIN{ split(ptrn, tmp, "\0"); lngth=gsub("\0", "", ptrn ) }
$0 ~ tmp[++fieldNr]{ buf=(buf==""?"": buf OFS) NR":"$0 ;
                     if ( fieldNr == lngth ) { print buf; exit }
                     next
                   }
{ fieldNr=0; buf="" }' infile
```

this will give you the line number followed by the matched line content; here we used "Partial Regexp Match" using the patterns from the "*ptrn*" against the lines.
see [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65621325/4023950) for other matching options.

we used NUL character `\0` to separate patterns.

---

Sample input:

```
AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB

CCCCCCCCC
AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
ccccccccc
123AAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB123
123CCCCCCCCC3
```

Output:

```
8:123AAAAAAAAA 9:BBBBBBBBB123 10:123CCCCCCCCC3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun with good old `awk`

```
cat file | wc -l
21287021
```

with > 3000,000 matches

```
time awk 'BEGIN{getline; a=$0; getline; b=$0}
       $0~/^C+$/ && a~/^A+$/ && b~/^B+$/{print "match starting on line "NR-2 }{a=b;b=$0}' file

real    0m12.644s
user    0m7.149s
sys     0m4.314s
```

Compared with `rg`on my machine

```
time rg -U 'A+\nB+\nC+' file
real    0m40.322s
user    0m16.503s
sys     0m17.246s
```